# Implement same RSA encryption on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, rsa

I have iOS sources for data encoding and I try to implement same encoding in Android app. iOS sources:

```
- (NSString *)encryptRSA:(NSString *)plainTextString useKeyWithTag:(NSString *)tag withSecPadding:(SecPadding)padding {
    SecKeyRef publicKey = [self _getPublicKeyRefByTag:tag];
    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
    uint8_t *nonce = (uint8_t *)[plainTextString UTF8String];
    SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
                  padding,
                  nonce,
                  strlen( (char*)nonce ),
                  &cipherBuffer[0],
                  &cipherBufferSize);
    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
    free(cipherBuffer);
    return [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

Function call:

```
[self.rsaManager encryptRSA:inputText withSecPadding:kSecPaddingPKCS1];
```

In Android I make next:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] text, PublicKey key) throws Exception {
  final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding");

  // encrypt the plain text using the public key
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
  return cipher.doFinal(text);
}
```

Function call:

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypt(inputText.getBytes(), publicKey))
```

In result I get different strings on iOS and Android for same `inputText`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Interoperability should be checked by encryption+deception.

Comment: you can try [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) as it provides library for all platforms or you can check from there whats wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKCS1 padding adds an element of randomness into the encryption. If you encrypt the same thing twice, you should get different ciphertexts. But both ciphertexts should decrypt to the same plaintext (modulo the added randomness, which should be handled by the PKCS1 implementation).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding

Comment: OP doesn't use OAEP, but rather PKCS#1 v1.5 padding which is also randomized. It's described in RFC 3447 section 7.2.1